# How to save the state of the map when switching between fragments?

Tags: android

When I switch the fragment to another and return to the map, then Google Map _map is equal to null.

Suppose I moved around the map, then moved to another fragment and returned to the map. And when I return to the card, it is overloaded.

How to solve this problem. Many thanks ! And then I don’t know what to do. What are your options? Maybe someone has already worked on this?

```
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap _map;

    // The geographical location where the device is currently located. That is, the last-known
    // location retrieved by the Fused Location Provider.
    private Location _mLastKnownLocation;

    SharedManager _manager;
    Connect _connect;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _manager = new SharedManager(getActivity());
        _connect = new Connect();

        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            _mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            _mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
        _mFusedLocationProviderClient = 
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
       }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        //BuildMap
        initializeMap();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (_map != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, _map.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, _mLastKnownLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        _map = googleMap;

        _map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        _map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Prompt the user for permission.
        getLocationPermission();

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        getDeviceLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
     */
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (_mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = _mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Location> 
                () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            _mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (_mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                _map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(_mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                _mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            _map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            _map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prompts the user for permission to use the device location.
     */
    private void getLocationPermission() {
        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this.getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            _mLocationPermissionGranted = true;

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            updateLocationUI();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        _mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    _mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (_map == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (_mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                _map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                _map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                _map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                _map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                _mLastKnownLocation = null;
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Build the map.
    private void initializeMap() {
        if (_map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)
                    getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_View);
            assert mapFrag != null;
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple inter-`Fragment` communication problem. You have several options here:

1) Apply one of the MV* approaches (MVP/MVVM/MVI), which separate the presentation layer from all logic and view. These are fairly complex and I'd not be able to explain here in detail. Also, if you'd be familiar with these, you won't have asked this question in the first place.

2) A simplest (not the best), approach would be to make use of the Application class (given it follows the `Singleton` pattern), or virtually any other `Singleton` class at your disposal. Just save the data there in `Fragment` **A** and retrieve from `Fragement` **B**. There are downsides of this, as you increase the cohesion between instances and rely on `Singleton` pattern.

3) Another simple and more preferrable way, would be to establish a 2-way communication between your `Activity` and your `Fragment`(s) with simple interfaces (callbacks). Just declare a callback interface in `Activity` (or implement it) and pass it to `Fragments`. Hence, now you can transfer between them and store the data in `Activity` during `Fragment` changes.